# Bootstrap typeahed multiple values. Fork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap

I read here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2007 that it was opened a pull request for adding support for multiple selections in Typeahead. I don't understand github, pull requests very well, so I wonder where I can find this updated js file?
I work in Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository that contains the code you are looking for is https://github.com/codeimpossible/bootstrap

#### How pull requests work

Pull requests are sent by someone (in this case `codeimpossible`) to the original owner of a forked repository. That means that codeimpossible has a version of the bootstrap repository https://github.com/codeimpossible/bootstrap whereas twitter's original original repository is https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.

With the pull request he is asking them to merge his changes back into their repository (and subsequent new versions of twitter bootstrap. If the pull request is successful (follow the comment thread on that page to the end!) you will eventually get the code from twitters repository.

In this case however, the pull request was not accepted and you will only find the code on https://github.com/codeimpossible/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I finally understood what pull request means

Comment: Wait. I downloaded the bootstrap code form codeimpossible repo, but the typeahed file is the still the same..